# Create PDF's on Google App-Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf

Long story short: is there any way to create PDF's on Google App-Engine for Java, besides PDFJet? I'm trying to do it via converting (X)HTML to PDF or something similar, but I can't find any solutions. I've also looked at iText XML Worker, but it has a huge list of incompatibility problems with CSS properties (http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance%20-list.htm).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I don't think so. The answer to the question you linked talks about PDFJet and iText, which the OP already tried and found that they aren't good enaugh for the requirements

Comment: I use https://pdfcrowd.com because the volume for me does not justify the effort of building my own solution.

Comment: @BackSlash I know, but if an additional one be available shouldn't be present in that one's answer as well?

Comment: @BackSlash: at least now the Q's are linked, for whenever someone compiles the answers into a complete wiki answer that all can be duped to.